# How to remove welcome to message?

Tags: 7

I changed the:

```
configuration: Site Name --> 'my site name'
```

But it shows in title bar like this:

> Welcome to 'my site name'

So, how can I remove the "Welcome to" in the title bar, so that the result would be just:

`'my site name'`

---

When I inspected the html I found like this:

```
Welcome to my stie name | my site name
```

But I wanted to be :

```
my site name
```

And I'm using zen base theme and zenophile sub-theme.

Comment: It's probably defined in the theme you are using. But there may be a few other places, too. We can but guess. Only solid data is "find a place where it comes from, and remove it", but that hardly helps. You can try to `grep` your Drupal directory for these words.

Comment: please give me a solution. I couldn't find anywhere.

Comment: We are knowledge base, not a support center. If you need more attention, in 46 hours you will be allowed to post bounty. Until then, patience. Or provide more information. Like the theme you are using. And if changing it to one of the built-in themes helps? When making full text search, in which files "Welcome to" is found? And so on - edits with meaningful data.

Comment: I just found this solution [I just had to replace the variable $title with $site_name.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570153/remove-welcome-to-on-drupals-seven-theme) but couldn't understand....

Comment: As @Mołot said it should be defined in your `page.tpl.php` Open the file and check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Page Title module and configure the Page title for Front Page.

- Download & enable https://drupal.org/project/page_title module.
  Configure Page Title from admin/config/search/page-title And change
  the **Frontpage**.

Comment: But I've also to install token.

Answer (score 1):

in your template.php

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (drupal_is_front_page()) {                 
    drupal_set_title(''); //removes welcome message (page title)
  }
}
```

dont forget to clear cache.

Comment: I've tried this but not worked...but wait didn't clear the cache, let me try it...

Comment: not working, really...

Comment: I think this solution is for body title but I wanted to remove from title bar of the window.. thank you...

Comment: you replace "THEME" by the name of your template ?

Comment: yeah, not working...

Answer (score -1):

if you want to remove for all your project so you can comment this line in node module.
in this address : Drupal core/modules/node/node.module
and comment line for default message.